# best scala idiom for find & return

Tags: scala, scala-collections

This is something I encounter frequently, but I don't know the elegant way of doing. I have a collection of Foo objects. Foo has a method bar() that may return null or a Bar object. I want to scan the collection, calling each object's bar() method and stop on the first one returning an actual reference and return that reference from the scan.

Obviously:

foos.find(_.bar != null).bar

does the trick, but calls #bar twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with any `Iterable` by using `iterator` (which evaluates lazily--it's called `elements` in 2.7).  Try this out:

```
case class Foo(i: Int) {
  def bar = {
    println("Calling bar from Foo("+i+")")
    (if ((i%4)==0) "bar says "+i else null)
  }
}
val foos = List(Foo(1),Foo(2),Foo(3),Foo(4),Foo(5),Foo(6))
foos.iterator.map(_.bar).find(_!=null)
```

Comment: is there a difference between this and using a projection?

Comment: Memoization of Stream[T] is the difference `val mapped = foos.elements.map(_.bar); mapped.find(_!=null);mapped.find(_!=null)` returns `Some(bar say 4)` and `None` where `val mapped = foos.projection.map(_.bar); mapped.find(_!=null);mapped.find(_!=null)` returns twice `Some(bar say 4)`.

Comment: `foos.view` in Scala 2.8 returns the same as `foos.projection` but evaluates the elements twice (does no memoization).

Comment: Use projections if you want to use the result multiple times (or some of the small set of methods available only on projections); otherwise, iterators are cheaper since they don't bother saving state.

Answer (score 8):

Working on the Stream[T] returned by [Seq.projection](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Seq.html#projection) is a nice trick

```
foos.projection map (_.bar) find (_.size > 0)
```

This will map the values needed to execute find.

In Scala 2.8 it's:

```
foos.view map (_.bar) find (_.size > 0)
```